# How to move an image(type png) in both directions on touch in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I want to rotate a png image on LinearLayout when the user drag that image in left or right direction.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SurfaceView` or `View` class to achieve this task go through below link :

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-surfaceview-run-in-thread-with.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html